# SyntaxError: Unexpected token - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been spending so much time on this one. I get the following error when running the code but cannot see what is the problem :

paper-full.js:13364 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (43:14)

Can anybody tell me what's wrong ?

```
var color = ['#8ACEDB', '#FFBEBE', '#CBFF40'];

function Apple(center) {
    var dest, vector, vit;
    this.center = center;
    var rad = 5 + Math.random() * 10;
    this.rad = rad;
    this.vit = 200 + (Math.random() * 200);
    this.path = new Path.Circle([0,0], this.rad);
    this.path.position = this.center;
    this.path.fillColor = color[Math.round(Math.random() * 2)];
    this.path.blendMode = 'multiply';
    this.dest = new Point.random() * view.size ;
}
Apple.prototype.move = function(){
    this.vector = this.dest - this.path.position;
    this.path.position += this.vector/this.vit;
    if(this.vector.length < 2){
    this.dest = new Point.random() * view.size ;
    }
}
var Basket = [];
var nb = 30;
for(var i =0; i < nb; i++){
    var center = Point.random() * view.size;
    Basket.push(new Apple(center));
}

function onFrame(event){
    for(var i =0; i < nb; i++){
        Basket[i].move();
    }
}

///////////  MOUSE
var mousePath;

function onMouseDown(event){
    mousePath = new Path({
    segments: [event.point],
    strokeColor = 'black',
    fullySelected : true
    });
}

function onMouseDrag(event){
    mousePath.add(event.point);
}

function onMouseUp(event){
    path.simplify(10);
}
```

Comment: `strokeColor = 'black'` should be `strokeColor: 'black'`. Firefox gave me a much nicer error message, but also you could have looked for line 43, column 14, which is what "43:14" means.

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 1):

change `=` to `:` for strokeColor:

```
function onMouseDown(event){
    mousePath = new Path({
    segments: [event.point],
    strokeColor = 'black', CHANGE THE = to :
    fullySelected : true
    });
}
```

In addition to looking in the console, for quick stuff like this, its helpful to post it a online editor and see if it throws any errors:
[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/poveti/1/edit?js,console)